# How to handle a situation when assignee is no more available?

Tags: activiti

I want to know if there is a best practice for a scenario when a user task is assigned to a user but user is nor more available(like, user has left the organization).

I can think of a timer boundary event to handle it, but are there better alternatives available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to re-assign the tasks when the user is no longer available. Use a java-based bean (or better a process to follow) to query the tasks based on user assignment and re-assign those task.

This is efficient than adding a timer-task to every user task.

Comment: But how would system come to know that user is no more availalbe? Currently, when user logs in, system either hand over his/her older task or assigns a brand new task. But if user doesn't login system would never come to know about user's unavailability.

Comment: If you are managing users in Activiti then you are probably good with a timer-task. however if users are managed outside (i.e. via AD or LDAP) then you can find out if users has been deleted and based on that call the service